# PayPal Pro : is it sufficient to check for non valid credit card numbers?

Tags: paypal, luhn

Right before doing a PayPal Pro payment, I check the credit card number with the Luhn algorithm. I know this only rules out invalid numbers, not malicious attacks (valid but non authentic numbers).

Is it still considered acceptable to proceed this way, or is it absolutely necessary for any online payment system to check if CC numbers are authentic meaning they match real cards? If it is, then is there a simple way to achieve that?

Comment: If I need online payments, it's normally handled securely elsewhere - and not something I need to know - then get a callback to approve

Answer (score 0):

While it's not absolutely necessary, verifying the card will help you control variables that can negatively affect customer experience. This won't guarantee availability of a sufficient credit limit to complete the order, but it catches the far more common problems of typos and similar issues.

Here is [PayPal's description of the process](https://cms.paypal.com/ca/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_admin_authcapture), which they term Authorization/Capture. And here's the documentation page that includes the [API calls for Authorization/Capture](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/WPWebsitePaymentsPro).